unity 2022 HDRP: How to bypass SkinnedMeshRenderer bakeMesh vertices in a texture to shadergraph via ComputeShader?
I just using a SkinnedMeshRenderer and a computeShader and a bakeMesh() and creating a RenderTexture from this. But when I save the texture in exr format I get a striped picture. So how can yi save the vertices into a texture and use it in the Shadergraph?
Thanks
Some more Details
my compute shader
#pragma kernel RunThis
StructuredBuffer computeInVertexPositions; RWTexture2D computeOutTexture;
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void RunThis (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    if (id.x < computeInVertexPositions.Length)
    {
        float3 v = computeInVertexPositions[id.x];
        computeOutTexture[id.xy] = float4(v, 1.0); 
    }
}

c# side
vertexToTexture2DComputeShader.SetBuffer(_kernelHandle, ComputeInVertexPositions, cb);
vertexToTexture2DComputeShader.SetTexture(_kernelHandle, ComputeOutTexture, _renderTextures[i]);
vertexToTexture2DComputeShader.Dispatch(_kernelHandle,
                                    Mathf.CeilToInt(RenderTextureSize / (float)ThreadGroupX),
                                    Mathf.CeilToInt(RenderTextureSize / (float)ThreadGroupY),
                                    ThreadGroupZ);

my shaderGraph

the generated texture

Somebody please help!
